# How to show Cluster for MKPolyline with geojson data View in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, markerclusterer, mkpolyline

I am loading `Mapview` with `geojson` data. It contains 7000 data in that geojson file. Even I loaded that data into `Mapview`. Its loaded fine, but, the problem is mapview getting freezing/stucking for few seconds while zoomin/zoomou So, its getting very bad user experience.

Even, I loaded the data in background thread, still mapview getting freeze.

After I read few forums, we can load clusters to avoid this kind freeze UI issue for mapview, but, I did not found for geojson data loading with clusters and for `MKpolylines`. I am showing in my mapview `Polylines` and `Annoations` by loading 2 `geojson` files to `MKMapview`.

> Anyone can suggest me, how to show clusters for MKPolylines and
>   Annotations by loading with geojson files.

For more info please check this following link which I have raised query for my mapview freezing issue.

[MapView getting freezing for few seconds while loading thousands of data and zoom-in time in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360012/mapview-getting-freezing-for-few-seconds-while-loading-thousands-of-data-and-zoo)

Comment: I am also looking for same solution.

Comment: if you found in future, ping solution, it would help.

Comment: @AbinBaby any idea about this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506729/how-to-validate-whether-user-tapped-on-mkpolyline-or-outside-of-the-polyline-in